# table pagination and filtering with javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

Let's say that you have to generate and display a table after querying a database using PHP. The table might have a lot of rows. One must be able to filter the resulting table using different criteria (single or multiple selections), much like an Excel table.

example:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|         id    |     name      |   type      |    description   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| input search  | input search  | drop down   | drop down        |
| by id field   | by name field | type select | sort asc/desc    |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| 1             | exampe_name   | type 1      | bla bla          |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| 2             | exampe_name 2 | type 2      | tra la la        |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
| ...           | ...           | ...         | ...              |
+---------------+---------------+-------------+------------------+
```

So, I imagined that there should be two pages:

- one that generates rows and apply selected filters($_GET) on request
- a second page which displays the table, using some javascript stuff to keep track of the selected criteria, pagination, reload content on filter change and smooth display...

Has anybody encountered such kind of tasks? If yes, please share your solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following: [ORIGINAL URL Removed...]
Might that be what you're looking to do?

Based on @dunc's comment I removed the original URL - looks like we can repalce it with [tablefilter.free.fr](http://tablefilter.free.fr) (the other option the OP found)

Comment: Found another one. It's better because it supports miltiple filters and can be easily customized - http://tablefilter.free.fr, very nice!

Comment: For anybody looking at this question historically, as of Jan 2013 the website in Jason's question leads to a spam-type lifestyle page with horrible javascript alerts. I would avoid!